# URL with parameters are not working in Ngnix Server

Tags: php, nginx

I have small application developed in php. I am trying to access my phpfile from browser. I am using Ngnix server.

When I hit **localhost/result.php** it shows the echo message. But when I try to pass parameters in the url **localhost/result.php/?phone=1234567890** , It gives

> 404 Page not found message.

Anyone who have faced this issue or know the solution, please let me know.

Comment: Please post your nginx configuration.

Comment: Did you mean to add an extra `/` before the `?`?

Comment: @RichardSmith I mean when I pass variable after filename in URL, it doesn't treat it as variable and give me 404 'Page Not Found' error.

Comment: You have a filename `/result.php` and you have a query string `?phone=12345`. Why is there a `/` in between the two? It changes `/result.php` to `/result.php/` which looks like a directory and (may) be the cause of your 404 response.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your nginx configuration has something similar to the below line in the `location` block. The ?query_string at the end of it, ensures that it is passed along in your request.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$query_string;
```

Comment: I have not used nginx before. Can you please tell me where I can check this?

Comment: Please check this blog on how to set up nginx configuration. https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx